# Add CSS style using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a chrome extension in which some icons are shown in a blank tab. I am using javascript to add the icons in the page. Below are the code snippets:

HTML:

```
<div id="icons" class="icons"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function addIcons() {
  for (var i = 0; i < iconArray.length; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = linkArray[i];

    var icon = document.createElement('img');
    icon.src = "images/" + iconArray[i];
    icon.title = titleArray[i];

    link.appendChild(icon);
    document.getElementById('icons').appendChild(link);
  }
  document.getElementById('icons').style.borderBottom="2px solid blue";
}
```

The problem is that the border is appearing above the icons(The border should appear below!). Can anybody tell me what should be done to get the desired result?

Comment: Soumen, can you try using padding or margin to push the border below the icons? (I'm not sure which is best as I'm speculating.) Hope that might help. Also, @deadrunk makes a good point. Make sure your HTML is validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried your code and it works correctly.

Screenshot: https://skitch.com/runk/83fes, latest Chrome.

Are you sure you have a valid html markup on the rest of the page? May be problem with it.

And I'd suggest not to set a css style via js.

```
<div id="icons" class="icons" style="border-bottom: 2px solid blue"></div>
```

Or using css style tag (file)

```
<style>
.icons { border-bottom: 2px solid blue }
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Check http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-bottom for setting bottom border for any DOM element.

Comment: Can you provide an example here rather than just referencing a link?

Comment: e.g.  `document.getElementById('icons').style.border-bottom="2px solid blue";` --OR-- `document.getElementById('icons').style.border-bottom-color="blue"; document.getElementById('icons').style.border-bottom-width="2px";document.getElementById('icons').style.border-bottom-style="solid";`

Comment: Not in the comments. Use the **edit** link and put it in the answer. Also, you might explain how your example is different or better than what the op is using in his code. In other words, how does your proposed solution solve the problem?

Comment: `document.getElementById('icons').style.border-bottom="2px solid blue"` isn't a valid js code